# right way to update an object returned by findOne in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

New to Node and sequelize. Looking for a way to update certain fields (or even just the updatedAt timestamp) when an object is touched. Let's assume I have the below query

```
//query is just for demo purposes - assume email is unique 
let existingEmployee = await employee.findOne(
  {
    where: { email: email} 
  }
);
```

I just need to update a certain field say designation

```
empObj = {//fields here}
existingEmployee.update(empObj)
```

does not seem to do anything. It does not change the updatedAt time stamp. Only new creates seem to add it.

If I need to say update just the updatedAt field which is a timestamp what do I do?

The model does have

```
defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
```

Should it not automatically populate the timestamp whenever the object is touched? Our requirement is to track commits to the db, even if the other fields have the exact same data.

Comment: Did you try `existingEmployee.update({ updatedAt: new Date()}) `?

Comment: When I first saved the data updatedAt was automagically populated. I was under the impression that updatedAt would be changed whenever the object is touched. Have defined the model with defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'), Should we do this explicitly? Or is it smart enough to know that when the commited data does not change it does not change updated?

Comment: you need to update `updatedAt` only if you have to update a record without changing any fields

Comment: Got it. If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `existingEmployee.update({ updatedAt: new Date()})` in order to update a record without changing any fields.
Sequelize does nothing if there is no props to update.